# CakePHP auth URL with get params

Tags: url, cakephp, authentication

I'm using CakePHP and I would like to authenticate my user with a key in the URL
like `/blog/users/login/key => /blog/users/login/FGHDFgFDg`

I know it's not secure and everything but for my needs it has do be done like that.

Have you any ideas how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

look at my Qlogins: http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/08/qlogin-quicklogins-fur-cakephp/

they provide what you want. it could be considered secure as long as the emails cannot be intercepted and you use https. also a token should only be valid once.
the default is "as often as you want", though. just bear that in mind.

I use it for sending emails (to specific content behind the login) to quickly jump to. if the user always had to login most would not bother going there. what your use case is, I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

In `UsersController.php`:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    function login($key = null) {
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'key' => $key // replace 'key' with your column that stores the key
            )
        ));

        if ($user != null) {
            $this->Auth->login($user);
            $this->redirect('/users/home');
        }
    }
}
```